# Yield call timeout after 60 seconds when calling api in React Redux-Saga

Tags: reactjs, django-rest-framework, react-redux, redux-saga

In my rest API backend(django), I do heavy processing and usually, it takes 1.5 minutes to produce a result, in that time I'm getting this error in my frontend react application.

```
export function* create(action) {
  try {
    const { payload } = action;
    const response = yield call(api.addPost, payload); **//can i set timout for this api call, here timeout after 60 second **  
    if (response.status === 200) {
      console.log('pass 200 check');
      yield put(appActions.setResourceResponse(response.data));
      console.log(response.data);
      payload.push('/add-news');
    }
  } catch (error) {
    console.log(error);
    yield put(
      a.setResponse({
        message: error.response.data,
        status: error.response.status,
      }),
    );
  }
}
```

**Error: timeout of 60000ms exceeded**

So, peer connection is lost.

How do I set request timeout in redux-saga

Comment: what are you using to make the api call? something like fetch or axios?

Answer (score 1):

If you are using axios, you could change the timeout setting like this.

```
axios({
    method: 'post',
    url: 'http://127.0.0.1:9000',
    timeout: 60 * 2 * 1000, // Let's say you want to wait at least 2 mins
    data: {
      id: '1234',
    }
  })
```

Comment: i have set axios.defaults.timeout = 1000. it worked. Thanks for your help

Comment: Great to hear! If all is well please approve the answer! (https://stackoverflow.com/help/someone-answers)